# The bones in the hand won't move the mesh, and symmetrize's not working either. Can you help?

Tags: rigging

So I've been trying to rig my characters for a week, and I can't find anything on the internet. I'm a complete beginner in blender, I need the characters for my unity game. The bones are looking like this:

[image: My character]

I attached the amature with automatic weights, and this happens:

[image: I moved the bone in the hand]

Also symmetrize's not working. I understand that it symmetrizes on the x axis, but even if I rotate the whole thing  it just wont work:

[[image: Symmetrize]

I tried everything, even unparented before symmetrizeing, rotating nothing happens, or it symmetrizes on the wrong axis.

Comment: In order to symmetrize your bones, make sure you have given them proper names. Ending with .L or .R depending on which side they are on. Select arm bones, right click, select names, then select left/right.

Comment: Symmetrize works with naming convention ... only if bones on right side are named with "R" letter at the end of each bone ....https://youtu.be/jhs3e6RRmlA

Comment: Thank you so much :D! Symmetrize's working now.

Comment: Everything's working fine :). You're the best